# How do I add a JavaScript library only once?

Tags: javascript

We have an odd framework here. We have different functions that try to add dependent libraries.

My question is, is there a way to add the library only once?

For example, if jQuery is already loaded, is there a generic way to NOT load jQuery again?

Based on the URL perhaps?

I am looking for an outcome similar to what `require_once` achieves in PHP.

Comment: When you say “load”, do you mean that the file is only downloaded once, or that the global jQuery object is only instantiated once?

Comment: `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { // jQuery is not loaded so load it }`

Comment: Plain JS does not support a require_once. HTML neither does. You must ensure it as @adaam said - it is also the technique used in C headers.

Comment: jQuery does not support it by itself, so including two consecutive versions of jquery is troublesome since the last version WILL overwrite the former versions imported. You have to use 3rd party libraries to perform the inclusions, like RequireJS

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for that or even [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/)

Here they explain you how to use RequireJS to avoid conflicts: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap

Comment: Yes. Browsers support type of dependency management. If this is a need for your project, you need to use a dependency manager, or write something similar yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a client-side library to do this, such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or you could implement a server-side solution. I do not know php very well, however the idea would be to have a client-side resource manager object that lives in a sandboxed scope (one per client http request). That object would implement a method such as `loadResource`, which would ensure the resource gets loaded once only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'generic' way to load javascript library only once. When a javascript is loaded, it's executed and injected directly into the global domain, and there would be no 'generic' trace you can track it down. It's more of the remote javascript's responsibility to make sure that itself cannot be loaded more than once.
There are, however, clever tricks that can be done here. Instead of loading the the javascript directly using the script tag, use a init() function to 'inject' the dependencies, and there you have a chance to verify if the script has been loaded or not. For example, if you use jQuery, do something like this:

```
var jsCache = {};
function init() {
    if (jsCache[myJavascript]) {
        return;
    }
    $.getScript("my_javascript.js").done( function() {
        jsCache[myJavascript] = true;
    }
}
init();
```

Not perfect, but should serve the purpose. If possible, use requiejs (http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), but yes, you have to modularize your scripts into AMD modules.